# How to do Union Query using Jetbrains Exposed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am facing problem when trying to do union query. I have multiple database tables (sharded tables). I have a list of all the table names. I want to do a union query on all the tables by looping through the list and creating a union query.

Code example:

```
fun main() {
    val tables = listOf("table_1", "table_2", "table_3")
    var finalQuery: Query? = null;
    for (table in tables) {
        var query = Model.selectAll();
        if(finalQuery == null){
            finalQuery = query;
        }else{
            finalQuery.union(query);
        }
    }
    
    println(finalQuery.get().toList())

}
```

The problem I am facing here is, at the end of the loop final query only has the value of the last query. So, basically the query object inside the loop is referencing the same memory every time.

I have tried to use clone() method but the result is same. Currently, I am doing separate queries to each table, so if there are 3 tables, I am doing 3 queries. I want to minimize it to one union call only.

Comment: I don't know this framework, but are you sure `finalQuery.union(query);` is correct? Maybe it should be `finalQuery = finalQuery.union(query);`?

Comment: Tried that as well, result is the same

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts there:

```kotlin
finalQuery.union(query)
```

`union()` doesn't mutate the original query, it returns a new query.

This wouldn't work, though:

```kotlin
finalQuery = finalQuery.union(query)
```

That's because `union()` returns a `Union`, not a `Query`.

If you want to keep your approach, you can force cast:

```kotlin
finalQuery = finalQuery.union(query) as? Query
```

Sidenote:
I guess this

```kotlin
var query = Model.selectAll()
```

Is a typo, since by your logic, it should be

```kotlin
val query = table.selectAll()
```

Comment: It's not working, tried this after union table name is updated with the last updated value of query

Comment: @SubhadipDasGupta Sorry, it's not clear to me what did you try to do and what's not working now. I'd suggest you either post the updated code our you can also ask your question on kotlinlang.slack.com in the #exposed channel